# Resolving "The Office System Pack cannot be installed on this system because the languages are not the same." installation error

Tags: setup, installer, runtime, microsoft-access-2002

I've inherited some software that runs on the Access 2002 Runtime. I am taking over development and support.

The installer halts with the following error message (installing on Windows XP):

> Visual Basic 6.0 Setup Toolkit
>
> The Office System Pack cannot be installed on this system because the
>   languages are not the same. Install the Office System Pack for the
>   appropriate language on your computer.

My system language is en-GB and the installer seems to require en-US be set as the system locale which requires a system reboot. Most users are in the UK so this will be a problem.

Can this be resolved on an existing setup package or must it be resolved by creating a new package? The former is very preferable. Thanks.

Comment: Other solutions I found include installing the run-time first and then copying the application files over, by-passing the installer. This, along with changing the system locale and rebooting (then changing it back), is not really acceptable because the software is being used by non-technical users who would most likely not want to go to that much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was able to resolve the problem by editing the ospfilelist.txt in the existing installer package, as per [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837150), without needing to create a new package.